# Where is default data directory in DB2?

Tags: backup, db2

I have a problem: cannot backup DB2 8.1 with backup command line in Windows 2003. I think my HDD was failure (after read error showed by backup command). So, I want to copy the folder/ directory which contains all of my data to send it to an IBM expert. But I don't know where is data saved. I install DB2 8.1 and everything was default when I create my database.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0024442.html

Comment: I think in Windows the default directory for database is c:\<instName> where instName could be DB2